# Prove that $\sum_{i \in A} i k_i = \sum_{i \in B} i \Rightarrow \sum_{i \in A} i^2 k_i \neq \sum_{i \in B} i^2$

Tags: summation

I would like to prove that, given two disjoint sets of integers A and B (with elements strictly greater than 1), and a sequence of integers $k_i > 0$, then $\sum_{i \in A} i k_i = \sum_{i \in B} i \Rightarrow \sum_{i \in A} i^2 k_i \neq \sum_{i \in B} i^2$

Comment: Not true for $A=B$ and $k_i \equiv 1$. Please show some context and work.

Comment: You are right, I added some constraints